# Should the Gemspec be packaged with a Ruby Gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I read that we [shouldn't package test files with a Ruby Gem](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/3207).

Now I'm wondering, if we should package the Gemspec.

For example, given the following Ruby Gem:

```
tree .
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.md
├── lib
│   └── simplegem.rb
├── simplegem.gemspec
└── test
    ├── simplegem_test.rb
    └── thing_test.rb

2 directories, 6 files
```

Should my [Gem::Specification](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/) look like:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift 'lib'
require 'simplegem'

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'simplegem'
  s.version     = Simplegem::VERSION
  s.licenses    = ['MIT']
  s.summary     = 'This is a simple gem!'
  s.description = 'Much longer explanation of the simple gem!'
  s.authors     = ['...']
  s.email       = '...'
  s.files       = %w(simplegem.gemspec
                     LICENSE.txt
                     README.md
                     lib/simplegem.rb)
  s.homepage    = 'https://github.com/mbigras'
end
```

Or:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift 'lib'
require 'simplegem'

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'simplegem'
  s.version     = Simplegem::VERSION
  s.licenses    = ['MIT']
  s.summary     = 'This is a simple gem!'
  s.description = 'Much longer explanation of the simple gem!'
  s.authors     = ['...']
  s.email       = '...'
  s.files       = %w(LICENSE.txt
                     README.md
                     lib/simplegem.rb)
  s.homepage    = 'https://github.com/mbigras'
end
```

Notice how the first includes `simplegem.gemspec` in the `s.files` array and the second does not.

- Should the Gemspec be packaged with a Ruby Gem?
- Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to pack a Gemspec with a Ruby gem, in a survey of the gems installed in one of my gem homes I noticed that in fact most gems don't include the gemspec file:

```
 ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7/gems $ find . -name \*.gemspec | wc -l
      95
 ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@happy-backend/gems $ ls | wc -l
     318
```

Why would you want to not pack it?

- It saves a few bytes in your GEM

Why pack it?

- It allows for easy unpacking and repackaging of a gem
- Why not? the gem spec is uploaded to the gem server anyway, so there are no secrets there and if the 'user' really wants it its going to be on the `$GEM_HOME/specifications` folder